# Show multiple lines

Tags: java

I created a basic order entry system where the customer is going to be able to put in the item they want and how many. 
After the put in the name and quantity I want them to be able  to select an option to add another item or as many more items they want. 
When they are done adding all the items they want it will give a display of each item they inputed.

It is all going to be done through command prompt

```
package stringvars;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewOrder {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String itemName = null;
    String itemQuantity = null;
    int continueOrder = 0;

    if(continueOrder == 0) {

            System.out.print("What item you would like? ");
            itemName = user_input.next();

            System.out.print("How much of item would you like? ");
            itemQuantity = user_input.next();

            System.out.print("Press 1 to order another item Press to 2 end");
            continueOrder = in.nextInt();
    }

    else(continueOrder == 2) {


    System.out.println("XYZ Company Order");
    System.out.println("Here is your order: ");
    System.out.println(itemQuantity + "of " + itemName);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: And your question is what?  And have you even tried doing your own homework?

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Fix your multiple and unnecessary scanners

Comment: That is literally 1/5th of the actual problem.  However, it's really not clear what the problem actually *is* from what we've been given, though.

Comment: @Makoto Good point, he should make for loops for iterate the times.